# SAS, Python, Excel Create Constantly Updating Function

Tags: python, excel, csv, dataset, sas

I have a very large dataset.  I've been working out of SAS; however I am open to working out of Python and excel (only excel with good details--I've never programmed here).  There is an identification number for each individual who has ordered (by time) observations row by row.  In some of the rows, I have a binary observation indicating a "success" or a "failure" marked by a 1 or a 0 respectively.  I'd like to add another three more columns (onto each row that contains a success/failure), that has the total number of successes (as they accumulate) and the total number of failures (as they accumulate) along withe the ratio between the two.  The ratio is trivial; however, I just don't know how to do the first two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

As an update:  Here is an idea of my dataset:

```
 ID     Success     Failure    totaSuccess    totalFailure    ratio

1234       -           -          -                -           -
1234       1           0          1                0         1/(1+0)
2345       -           -          -                -           -
2345       0           1          0                1         0/(1+0)
1234       0           1          1                1         1/(1+1)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide us some sample input and expected output. Plus what have you tried to achieve this.

Comment: You can sum the variable to get the total number of success, and count of the variable - number of success for failures.  You'll also have to decide what to do when the failure is 0, because you're then dividing by 0. More importantly you need to explain how the table is being updated and how you would need to account for that vs a one off solution.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I would provide some code (I usually do), but I have no clue right now what to use.

Comment: @Reese I am posting in the description

Comment: What is the missing value rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
PROC SORT DATA = HAVE;
    BY ID;
RUN;

DATA WANT / VIEW = WANT;
    SET HAVE;
    BY ID;

    IF FIRST.ID THEN DO;
        TOTALSUCCES = 0;
        TOTALFAILURE = 0;
    END;

    TOTALSUCCES + SUCCESS;
    TOTALFAILURE + FAILURE;
RUN;
```

Comment: your answer was flagged as low-quality, which means that apparently it is not evident to everyone why and how your answer solves the problem. Maybe you could add some description and comments to explain what this piece of code does?

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you can create a view so that it updates as your table updates. Regardless of what solution you use, its important to clarify how your table is being updated.

```
data have;
do id=1 to 10;
    numobs=ceil(rand('uniform')*5);
    do i=1 to numobs;
        value=rand('bernoulli', 0.3);
        output;
    end;
end;
drop i numobs;
run;

proc sql;
    create view want as
    select id, value, sum(value) as success, count(value)-sum(value) as failure, sum(value)/(count(value)) as ratio
    from have
    group by id;
quit;
```